# When do we use 'revision' as a countable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

'Revision' might be countable or uncountable. I am a little bit confused.

Comment: This question can be a useful reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When **revision** means a *change*, it can be countable, as in *make a few revisions to a report.*

When it means *examining something so it can be changed*, then it can be both:
*a system in need of revision* AND *a revision of standards*.

Finally, when it means *learning for an exam*, it is always uncountable.

Comment: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/revision

Comment: 'Revisions of Standards' is a common expression referring to the several "revisions" published from time to time. Here it means published issues of revised standards.

Comment: @Irene If learning for the exam meaning of revision is always uncountable how can I say that I have read a paper for exam more then once and pointed out **on more then one**?

Comment: @speedyGonzales: You can say "It's advisable to do some revision before the exam" but not *"It's advisable to do **a** revision before the exam".

Answer (score 6):

Like most derived nouns, *revision* can refer to a number of things. In the case of *revise* (the verb that *revision* is derived from), at least the following senses can be distinguished:

1. *Revision* can refer to the **process** of revising: ***Some revision*** was necessary in Chapter 5.
2. *Revision* can refer to 1 or more **events** of revising: *There have been **six revisions** so far.*
3. *Revision* can refer to 1 or more **products** of revising : *This is **a revision**; I want the original.*

(2) and (3) can be combined: *I have **all six revisions** in my collection.*

Only in sense (1) is *revision* a mass noun; in the other two senses it's a count noun.

Answer (score 3):

Revision may be used plural e.g revisions; but singular form **revision** may also denote **a set of changes**.  So, at least it is safe to use plural form if you are talking about several sets of "change(s)". E.g:

> The plan underwent constant revisions.

On the other hand, with the meaning "study" or "review", you may use revision singular as in

> I have to do some history revision tonight

Comment: I see your first example as incorrect, with the following two forms preferable to it: "The plan underwent constant revision", "The plan underwent multiple revisions".

Comment: @jwpat, thank you. is this because of "constant"? As far as I know "constant" has a sense of "repeatedly".

Comment: I am confused. Wold you check [OED](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/constant) and [longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/constant_1)

Comment: As you note, [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/constant) [which should not be indicated by "OED"] uses the word *repeatedly*, meaning *recurring*, within its definition of *constant*.  To replace my previous comment, let me say that  *constant* need not imply *repeatedly*, nor vice versa; *ie* we can have constancy with or without repetition and repetition with or without constancy.